# Solve this algebra problem in terms of $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation for $x$ and $y$ give $xy+8x+y=83$. I did mine by isolating factoring $x$ and got $$x = \frac{83-y}{y+8}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ meant to be integers?

Comment: If you mean you got $$x=\frac{83-y}{8+y}$$ then you're right.

Comment: @Mathmo123, why would $\;x,y\;$ have to be integers and what has that to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @Timbuc It is a very possible condition that could've been left out in translation and transcription.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, it is trivial **anyway** , yet the point is that the OP asks for the correct form to isolate $\;x\;$ in terms of $\;y\;$, and it is tagged as "linear algebra". Nothing to do with integer, complex or whatever solutions (except modulo $\;2\;$ , of course)

Comment: If $x,y$ are both integers then one can view this as a more number theory based problem. In this case, the problem could be asking for all possible integer pairs of $(x, y)$, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

A hint for these things: turn the left-hand side into a product: $xy+8x+y+8=91$

Answer (score 1):

$x(y+8)=83-y$
$x=\frac{83-y}{y+8}$,$y\ne -8$
$y(x+1)=83-8x$
$y=\frac{83-8x}{x+1}$
$x\ne -1$

Answer (score 1):

It is almost correct. You would have to justify that $y+8\neq 0$: Write the equation as $(x+1)(y+8)=91$. 
 
Of course, this argument depends on the characteristic of your field $K$.
It assumes that $91\neq 0$ in $K$, which is not true for characteristic $7$ or $13$.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP has ever heard of that sort of field.

Comment: @Michael well, that's certainly a question. On the other hand he might enjoy it to discover, say, finite fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since no constraints were indicated on $x, y$, here's a solution that assumes that $x, y$ are both integers.

Continuing on from your factorization, we have:

$$x = \frac{91}{y + 8} - 1$$

Since $x$ is an integer, then it is necessary that $y + 8 \mid 91$. Hence, we can determine the list of possible integer pairs $(x, y)$ by first picking $y$ such that $y + 8 \mid 91$ and then computing $x$. Namely,

$$(x, y) = (-2, -99), (-8,-21),(-14,-15),(-92, -9), (90, -7), (12, -1), (6,5), (0, 83)$$